# Upgrade of OS stuck on 'Installing the upgrades'

Tags: upgrade

I am upgrading to a newer version of Ubuntu. It reached 'installing the upgrades' but has been stuck there for 2 hours, although the green bar animation is still moving left and right.

[image: Upgrading Ubuntu to version 20.04]

I'm still able to use the computer but I'm worried that if I restart then it will corrupt the system. Ubuntu seems so amazing that a big part of me feels like the developers wouldn't let something like that happen and would have a system....but I'm too scarred from Windows to take the risk.

Ubuntu 19.10 64bit was my old version.

Comment: Search this site for answers for upgrades from obsolete systems -- 19.10 is really no longer supported, so you probably need to change to the archive repos.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I tried to search those keywords but there's nothing related to my specific problem. If I cancel the installation and restart will my system still be ok or will it break do you think?

Comment: @ubfan1   I could only find one other question with the same problem (almost) but it received no reply. Any suggestions on what to search for or anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I needed to move the upgrade terminal window to the other side of the screen and behind it was another window that was asking something about the keyboard. I honestly don't remember what it said because I didn't think the issues were connected. I just clicked ok and then it resumed after 5 hours.

There wasn't any indication of the other window anywhere. Strange but glad to have fixed.

Comment: The launcher on the left edge of the screen should have an icon for these hidden windows, with little red dots when active.